# How to batch modify SAS programs with a SAS program?

Tags: sas

I know we can use data steps to infile "*.sas" programs as a dataset, each line of code is one record of the dataset. And then I can make changes to the dataset with SAS.

Let's say I have 100 programs already exist in c:\pgm, all I need to do is minor modifications, such as changing flag1 to flag2 for all these 100 program. If I don't want to open each program and substitute the flag one by one. Is there a way to get all program names in c:\pgm, so that I can loop over these names and do the substitution.

I'm using SAS 9.4 and EG. Thanks!

Comment: A .sas file is just a text file, you can do search/replace using OS commands. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/26cf789d6da0ce941e447022fdccf0f4 This finds the strings, changing it should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: http://www.phusewiki.org/docs/2006/P018.pdf

Comment: @Reeza OS / Filesystem access to the .sas files can't always be assumed.  I worked at a company where we only had EG, and had no direct access to the filesystem or OS.  I ended up writing a tool to do specifically what the OP is asking as well as a tool to perform diff's.  The only alternative in the OP's case may be to open up 100 projects one-by-one and make the changes.

Comment: The first link doesn't actually demonstrate an OS method, it's a SAS program using INFILE method.

Comment: Using a text editor like notepad++, which can do search &replaces in files, would be so much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

I might have overcomplicated it a bit, but the idea is the following:

- extract the list of all the sas files in folder
- create a macro variable array of these files
- make a loop and call editFile macro on each single extracted file.

```
%let dir=C:\prg;
%let var_prefix=vars_;

%macro batchEdit;
data _null_;
  pfad="&dir.";
  rc=filename("fileref",pfad);
  did=dopen("fileref");
  if did eq 0 then do;
    putlog "Dir does not exist";
    return;
  end;
  num=dnum(did);
  j=1;
  do i=1 to dnum(did);
    name=dread(did,i);
    if UPCASE(substrn(name,max(1,length(name)-3),4)) eq ".SAS" then do;
      call symput(CATS("&var_prefix.",j),name);
      j=j+1;
    end;
  end;
  call symput("varcnt",j);
  rc=dclose(did);
  rc=filename("fileref");
run;

  %DO j=1 %TO &varcnt.;
    %editFile(file=&&&var_prefix&j);
  %END;
%mend;

%macro editFile(file=);
%put In this Macro you should define what modification should be done on each single file;
%put Current File: &file.;
%mend;

%batchEdit;
```

P.S. I have tested it on unix SAS server, so it might require some modifications on PC SAS.